# AES Encryption Assistance

Tags: encryption, aes

I have a 116 character hex string that I need to AES encrypt then convert to Base64. I found the following AES Encryption code here at StackOverflow and from testing, it works like it should, at least I am getting the same result as the vendor. The problem I am having, according to a vendor's instructions, is "the resulting string should be 88 characters long, ending with two Padding characters." I am ending up with a 172 character Base64 string and I have no idea where the problem is. Any help would be greatly appreciated

```
Function EncryptFromStringToBytes(ByVal plainText As String) As Byte()
    Dim encrypted As Byte()
    'Create AES object
    Using AES As RijndaelManaged = New RijndaelManaged()
        AES.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7
        AES.KeySize = 256
        AES.Mode = CipherMode.CBC
        AES.Key = StringToByteArray(strSharedKey)
        AES.IV = StringToByteArray(strIV)
        'create an encryptor to perform stream transform
        Dim encryptor As ICryptoTransform = AES.CreateEncryptor(AES.Key, AES.IV)
        'create the streams used for encryption
        Using msEncrypt As MemoryStream = New MemoryStream()
            Using csEncrypt As CryptoStream = New CryptoStream(msEncrypt, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write)
                'write all data to the stream. Streamwriter will use the default UTF8 encoding if not specified.
                Using swEncrypt As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter(csEncrypt) ', System.Text.Encoding.ASCII)
                    swEncrypt.Write(plainText)
                End Using
                encrypted = msEncrypt.ToArray()
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using
    'return encrypted bytes from the memory stream and convert to Base64
    Return Convert.ToBase64String(encrypted)
    'TextBox3.Text = Len(encrypted)
    'Return encrypted

End Function
```

@Luke Joshua Park:
The IV, SharedKey and SharedSecret are given to me in Hx notation. 
The vendors instructions are:
1. Convert UTC Date/Time from UTF8 into Hx notation
    (resulting string is 50 Hx characters long.) - this is correct
2. Concatenate step1 + "7c" + SharedSecret
    (resulting string is 116 Hx characters long) - this is correct
3. AES encrypt step2 - I *think* this is where the problem is but I am getting the same test resulting value the vendor is getting
4. Convert step3 to Base64

This is the StringToByteArray() function:

```
    Function StringToByteArray(text As String) As Byte()
    Dim bytes As Byte() = New Byte(text.Length \ 2 - 1) {}
    For i As Integer = 0 To text.Length - 1 Step 2
        bytes(i \ 2) = Convert.ToByte(text.Substring(i, 2), 16)
    Next
    Return bytes
End Function
```

As a side note, how can I view the encrypted string in a textbox? If I use EncryptFromStringToBytes(CVr2.Text).ToString, it returns system.byte[] instead of the actual value.

Comment: Can you provide the exact set of instructions you received from "the vendor"?  Can you also please ensure you're providing a [mcve] - we can't see how you define `strIV` or anything like that.

Answer (score 1):

**Don't encrypt the 116 char hex string, but instead encrypt the 58 bytes that they represent.**

The 58 bytes will then give 64 bytes of encrypted data. 64 bytes is equal to 512 bits, and as base64 encodes 6 bit per character, you need 512/6 ~ 86 chars to encode it .. As base64 encodes in blocks of 4 characters, you will need 2 padding characters, and thuse ends up with a 88 characters base64 encoded string.

Comment: I apologize in advance but how do you encrypt the 58 bytes that they represent? If I understand correctly, use the StringToByteArray then encrypt that result?

Comment: Thanks Ebbe! I did the following and got the 88 character string with 2 padding "==". I did as you suggested, convert the starting string to a byte array, encrypt the byte array then convert to a Base 64 string and POOF!